# Unable to locate click the check box

Tags: selenium

Please help me the locate the check box and select. There are multiple check boxes, there is no way to locate them uniquely.
Here is the Code for one of such check box.

Thanks in Advance for the Help!!!

```html
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="height:65px">
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li>
 <md-input-container class="md-block">
                                     <md-checkbox value="$index+1check" class="checkbox ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched ng-empty" ng-model="item.Selectedd" ng-click="toggle($index+1, selected,item.TitleId,item)" icon,md-checkbox.md-checked._md-icon="{background-color: green;}" id="Cbk_List" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" aria-invalid="false" style=""><div class="_md-container md-ink-ripple" md-ink-ripple="" md-ink-ripple-checkbox=""><div class="_md-icon"></div></div><div ng-transclude="" class="_md-label">
                                     </div></md-checkbox>
                                 </md-input-container>
                 
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="manageTitle_CirclCard">
                                    <div class="ng-binding">2</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What about `tabindex` attribute for this check?? Is it unique or same for all??

Comment: And could you share more similar checkbox html as well..

Comment: There is an `id="Cbk_List"`, so you can use it as unique locator

Answer (score 0):

You should try to locate using `cssSelector` with it's attribute `tabindex` as below :-

```
#Cbk_List[tabindex='0']
```

**Edited** :- If checkbox element has not any attributes with unique value, you should try using `xpath` with `index`, assuming you want to get first checkbox element, then try below `xpath` :-

```
(.//*[@id = 'Cbk_List'])[1]
```

**Note** :- In above `xpath`, just change the index from `1` to desire one checkbox to find.

Comment: Saurabh, Thank you for your response. All the Check boxes have TabIndex=0

Comment: @Ambika Ok then use to locate unique element using `xpath` with index, try with updated answer and let me know..:)